# How to delete and update with applyBatch() in a ContentProvider?

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I am implementing a ContentProvider in my app. When operations are performed, I sent an `ACTION_UPDATED` broadcast so that various parts of my app that use this content provider know that they must re-query for the latest data.

I recently ran into a use case where I would like to batch multiple operations, specifically a `delete` and an `update`. As it stands today, my `ACTION_UPDATED` broadcast will be sent twice. This results in some funny UI updates. I looked into [`applyBatch()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProvider.html#applyBatch(java.util.ArrayList%3Candroid.content.ContentProviderOperation%3E)), but I cannot figure out how I would selectively send the `ACTION_UPDATED` broadcast based on whether or not the `update` or `delete` was a part of a batch, or just the normal flow.

I thought that in my implementation of `applyBatch()` I would be able to use the [`isDelete()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProviderOperation.html#isDelete()) and [`isUpdate()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentProviderOperation.html#isUpdate()) methods to call an internal version of my `delete` and `update` API which does not send the broadcast, and then at the end of my `applyBatch()` implementation I could send the broadcast just one single time. However, those APIs are only in API level 23+ and I need to support older than that.

Any suggestions?